# Create javascript object using php foreach

Tags: php, javascript

How can I create the following using a PHP `foreach` from an array?

```
var options = [
    {text: "one", value: 1},
    {text: "two", value: 2},
    {text: "three", value: 3},
    {text: "four", value: 4}
];
```

my PHP Array looks like the following :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => 25000
            [text] => 25,000
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => 25000
            [text] => 25,000
        )
)
```

Comment: How are the javascript and the php array related?

Comment: `text => text, 
value => value`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple JSON encode will do it:

```
echo "<script>var options = " . json_encode($array) . ';</script>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `json_encode()` will do the trick without any `foreach`. Note that you have to use utf-8-encoded text in PHP, otherwise it will fail.

Comment: You can use json_last_error() function to check for errors if encoding fails.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is not very correct, but you can do the following:

```
<script>
var options = [

<?php foreach ($myArrays as $AnArray) { ?> 
    {text: "<?php echo $AnArray['text']; ?>", value: <?php echo $AnArray['value']; ?>},
<?php
}
?>

];
</script>
```